# Container Leaking Into Sidebar

Tags: css, css-float, containers, dreamweaver, sidebar

Help! I'm a novice and I need some serious help fast! I have a two column layout that I used from dreamweaver's templates (2 column liquid) I got most of my site all ready to go, but when I opened it in a browsers, it looked completely different. The text and pictures in the `.container` are leaking over into the `.sidebar1`. I set the sidebar to `float: left`, and the container to `float: right`, but nothing I have tried is working. please help! I need to figure this out tonight! Please and Thank You!

```
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #C7776C;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    min-height: 160px;
    background-color: #E7C082;
}

.container {
    float: right;
    width: 993px;
    background-color: #FEF3C8; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to include the css or html or a screenshot of my problem. I'm happy to include it if someone can tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: Just copy&paste your code. It's fairly simple.

Comment: I tried that, it says it is too long by like 5000 characters.

Comment: Just post relevant code. The best thing to do is creating a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Sometimes the problem is solved during this step.

Comment: I'm a real novice. I tried creating a Fiddle, it didn't seem to give me much insight. I previously plugged all the code into another css checker, which also didn't help solve the problem. Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS code to:

```
.sidebar1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #C7776C;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.header {
    min-height: 160px;
    background-color: #E7C082;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 993px;
    background-color: #FEF3C8; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width,       centers the layout */
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pEdf2/2/